# My code doesn't work within a $(document).ready() function. Can anyone help me understand why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend, slideshow

I'm trying to learn how to create slideshows for a project at work. I'm using Jquery to store the active image in a variable and then using the next() method to append the active class to that image and remove the active class from the previous image.

Now that all works fine when I just have the function running on it's own. The moment I use a document.ready() function however, it doesn't work. I was able to log some messages to the console within it, but for some reason I couldn't run this function. Each time the console tells me that the slideSwitch function hasn't been defined.

Can anyone help me understand this?

Cheers.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
    function slideSwitch() {
        var $active = $('.active');
        var $next = $active.next();
        $next.addClass('active');
        $active.removeClass('active');
    }
    setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 5000 );
});
```

```css
#slideshow {
    position: relative;
    height: 400px;  
    width: 600px;
    margin: 15% auto;
}
.slide {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 8;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.active {
    z-index: 10;
}
.lastActive {
    z-index: 9;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="slideshow">
  <img class="slide active" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=0" alt="image of toscana, slideshow image 1" />
  <img class="slide" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=1" alt="image of toscana, slideshow image 1" />
  <img class="slide" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=2" alt="image of toscana, slideshow image 1" />
  <img class="slide" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=3" alt="image of toscana, slideshow image 1" />
</div>
```

When the slideshow works it basically just times out the images to create the impression of a slideshow, swapping the z-index values a bit like a deck of cards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing a *string* to `setInterval`, so it is evaluated in the *global* scope and your function is scoped to the anonymous function you pass to `ready` (so it isn't found).

*Never* pass a string to `setInterval`, always pass a function.

```
setInterval(slideSwitch, 5000 );
```